# Admin panel icons disappeared after wagtail update

Tags: wagtail

I have a problem with svg icons on my project.

There was a project on wagtail v2.3, after its consecutive update to version 2.12 icons disappeared from the admin panel.
Svg files are in the correct directory, html markup is correct. How do I fix this problem?

```
<li class="menu-item" data-explorer-menu-item="">
   <a class="" href="#" aria-haspopup="dialog">
      <span>
         <svg class="icon icon-folder-open-inverse icon--menuitem" aria-hidden="true">
            <use href="#icon-folder-open-inverse"></use>
         </svg>
      </span>
      Страницы
      <span>
         <svg class="icon icon-arrow-right icon--submenu-trigger" aria-hidden="true">
            <use href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
         </svg>
      </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

[wagtail svg icon issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7frr.png)

Comment: Do you have any error messages from dev DevTools (F12) Console? Is the html code you show us the source on the server, or what is seen in the browser (DevTools - Elements)?

Comment: I have only one warning message in firefox and chrome: `Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4:272`

Comment: Hm... You say the SVG icons are in the correct directory.  But I can't see any references to any files in the snippet you posted.   Are they in the CSS perhaps?  To me, the svg icons look empty.  Is there something hiding behind the <svg> classes?

Comment: Hey man. Did you manage to solve this problem somehow? I'm stuck at the same bug right now. Some guidance would be very helpful, thanks.